# Trace inequality property

Tags: matrices, inequality, trace

I need to show that for a matrix $\mathcal{Q} \in \mathcal{R}^{n\times n}$ with $Q^TQ = I$ and $H \in \mathcal{R}^{n\times n}$ positive semidefinite, we have the relation $Trace(HQ) \leq Trace(H)$.

Considering the SVD decomposition of H : H = $U\Sigma V^*$

I start the proof with the following : Trace(HQ) = Trace($U\Sigma V^*Q$) = Trace$((V^*QU)\Sigma)$

I the define : $X = V^*QU$ orthogonal, it's column all have unit length. This implies that $X_{ii} \leq 1$, since otherwise
the norm of column i would be too big.

Since $\sigma_{i} \geq 0\quad \forall i$, this argument shows that we can
maximize tr(RC) by taking $X = I_{n\times n}$.

Finally, i found that Trace(HQ) = Trace$((V^*QU)\Sigma)$ = Trace$(X\Sigma) \leq$ Trace($I\Sigma$) $\leq Trace(\Sigma)$

But i don't know how to make the last step to prove the relation.

Thanks,

Comment: Another approach: it suffices to note that the trace norm is unitarily invariant and that for any such norm, we have $\|AB\| \leq \|A\| \cdot |B|$ where $\|A\|$ is a trace norm and $|B|$ is a spectral norm

Answer (score 1):

$H$ is real symmetric. You may use orthogonal diagonalisation instead of SVD.

Comment: @Rima More explicitly: if $H = V\Sigma V^*$ is an orthogonal diagonalization, then $H$ and $\Sigma$ have the same trace.